# Cannot find ATSAMS70N21A-AN lead width and lead length?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, atmel, pcb-assembly, kicad

I have trying to make a breakout board for ATSAMS70N21A-AN. I then tried to design the footprint in KiCad, so when I was looking for the dimensions on the datasheet I couldn't find the lead width or length. Where would I find these dimensions? It is an R-LQ100_U Package.

Comment: [Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11242-32-bit-Cortex-M7-Microcontroller-SAM-S70Q-SAM-S70N-SAM-S70J_Datasheet.pdf) page 1548?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean LQFP-100.  It is available in the Kicad library `Housings_QFP` (standard but viewable here: https://github.com/KiCad/Housings_QFP.pretty) named `LQFP-100_14x14mm_Pitch0.5mm`